# Terraform Error: Incorrect condition type when running terraform plan

Tags: amazon-web-services, boolean, syntax-error, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

In code .tf file:

```
resource "aws_vpc_peering_connection" "this_1" {
  count         = var.create_peering_1 ? 1 : 0
  peer_owner_id = var.peer_account_id_1
  peer_vpc_id   = var.vpc_peer_id_1
  vpc_id        = module.vpc.vpc_id
  auto_accept   = var.auto_accept_peering_1
}
```

The variable in variables.tf:

```
variable "create_peering_1" {
  description = "Create peering connection, 0 to not create"
  default     = 0
}
```

The error I am getting:

```
Error: Incorrect condition type

  on peering_1.tf line 6, in resource "aws_vpc_peering_connection" "this_1":
   6:   count         = var.create_peering_1 ? 1 : 0
    |----------------
    | var.create_peering_1 is 0

The condition expression must be of type bool.
```

What should I do to fix this error?

Comment: Implicit conversion of non-bool to bool was an unsupported semi-accidental feature in old versions of Terraform. You need to use an explicit bool type such as `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
variable "create_peering_1" {
type = bool
default = true
```

and bool has to be either true or false.

Comment: I tried adding it but it still gives error:
Error: Invalid default value for variable
 on variables.tf line 109, in variable "create_peering_1":
 109:   default     = 0

This default value is not compatible with the variable's type constraint: bool
required.  @giridhar.j

Comment: ah, bool has to be either true or false. When true, count will be 1 and when false count will be 0 for the above code. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's confusing to use `0` as `false`

```
variable "create_peering_1" {
  description = "Create peering connection, false to not create"
  default     = false
  type        = bool
}
```